# proXPN via OpenVPN on 13.04

Tags: 13.04, openvpn

Is anyone currently managing to use proXPN via OpenVPN?

I tried using the config files from both the Mac and Windows downloads per these instructions: http://downgoat.net/2013/04/20/proxpn-openvpn-on-linux-configuration/

But I keep getting a timeout when I try to connect.

```
Oct  5 14:17:18 jonno-mythbuntu NetworkManager[1065]: <info> VPN: loaded org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp
Oct  5 14:17:18 jonno-mythbuntu NetworkManager[1065]: <info> VPN: loaded org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn
Oct  5 14:17:18 jonno-mythbuntu NetworkManager[1065]:    keyfile: parsing VPN connection 1 ...
Oct  5 14:17:18 jonno-mythbuntu NetworkManager[1065]:    keyfile:     read connection 'proXPN OpenVPN'
Oct  5 14:34:34 jonno-mythbuntu NetworkManager[1065]: <info> Starting VPN service 'openvpn'...
Oct  5 14:34:34 jonno-mythbuntu NetworkManager[1065]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn), PID 5105
Oct  5 14:34:34 jonno-mythbuntu NetworkManager[1065]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' appeared; activating connections
Oct  5 14:34:37 jonno-mythbuntu NetworkManager[1065]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: starting (3)
Oct  5 14:34:37 jonno-mythbuntu NetworkManager[1065]: <info> VPN connection 'proXPN OpenVPN' (Connect) reply received.
Oct  5 14:34:37 jonno-mythbuntu nm-openvpn[5118]: OpenVPN 2.2.1 x86_64-linux-gnu [SSL] [LZO2] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [PF_INET6] [IPv6 payload 20110424-2 (2.2RC2)] built on Feb 13 2013
Oct  5 14:35:18 jonno-mythbuntu NetworkManager[1065]: <warn> VPN connection 'proXPN OpenVPN' (IP Config Get) timeout exceeded.
```

Answer (score -1):

When you install proxpn there is a directory called config.. Generally you can just copy that over the config directory in openvpn clients and then hit connect.

Here are the openvpn server addresses:
Dallas: 107.6.100.3
NY: 173.231.141.114
NL: 213.179.208.131
UK: 78.157.207.131
LA: 64.27.29.67
Seattle: 216.18.231.179
Singapore: 223.27.170.51

When you are making your own custom config file, it should always have one of those addresses, like remote 107.6.100.3 443

We always use port 443 as the default, but we have 80 and 8080 ports mirrored in case there is some problem with 443

Here are the paid users ports blacklist:
20:21
25
8080
110
135:139
143
445
465
585
993
995
3389
5900:5999

You should choose a custom port if you want to run vnc or rdp. or connect via the real home ip address/port forwarding for those protocols.

Here are the list of available proXPN PPTP Server Locations:

Dallas: pptp.proxpn.com
New York: pptp-ny1a.proxpn.com
Los Angeles: pptp-la1.proxpn.com
Seattle: pptp-se1.proxpn.com
Netherlands: pptp-nl1.proxpn.com
UK: pptp-uk1.proxpn.com
Singapore: pptp-sg1a.proxpn.com

Title: poptop-nl
IP: 213.179.213.7

Title: pptp-la
IP: 64.27.29.68

Title: pptp-nl
IP: 213.179.213.7

Title: pptp-d1
IP: 107.6.100.5

Title: pptp-ukb
IP: 78.157.207.134

Title: pptp-se
IP: 216.18.231.181

Title: pptp-sg
IP: 223.27.170.53

Title: ppty-ny
IP: 173.231.141.116

Remote subnet and mask are supposed to be passed from the server -> user, so those are not static values so the user should leave those remote subnet and mask at 0.0.0.0 (default) mppe checked no domain name, just username.